# Cmdlets not found in command line but available in ISE

Tags: powershell, batch-file, iis, powershell-ise, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create an IIS application and app pool using PowerShell on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM. The powershell script is as follows:

```
Param(
    [string] $branchName,
    [string] $sourceFolder
)

if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
    [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{ 
    Write-Warning "You do not have Administrator rights to run this script.     `nPlease re-run this script as an Administrator."
    Exit
}

$appPool = $branchName
$site = "Default Web Site"

#Add APPPool
New-WebAppPool -Name $appPool -Force 

#Create Applications
New-WebApplication -Name $branchName -Site $site -PhysicalPath $sourceFolder -   ApplicationPool $appPool -Force
```

If I run the script in the PowerShell ISE it works fine but if I run it from a command line (or a batch file using the command line) I get the error

> The term New-WebAppPool is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet... etc.

Is there a way that the web administration cmdlets could be installed in the ISE but not the command line?

Comment: Please show the exact code you're running and the exact error that code produces. Also show the output of `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: You probably need to import the cmdlet explicit: `Import-Module WebAdministration`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're using PowerShell v2 (the default version installed with Server 2008 R2) it's as @jisaak suspected: you need to import the module `WebAdministration` explicitly in your code:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

ISE seems to do that automatically.

Another option would be to [upgrade to PowerShell v4](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20623.step-by-step-upgrading-the-powershell-version-4-on-2008-r2.aspx), which also automatically imports modules when one of their exported cmdlets is used.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the answer was painfully simple. As suggested, the solution was to import the module, but there was an issue was that it wasn't available after closing the console and reopening it. To solve this I simply had to add the line into the powershell itself so it imports the module at every runtime.

```
Param(

[string] $branchName,   
[string] $sourceFolder)

if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
[Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{ 
Write-Warning "You do not have Administrator rights to run this script.`nPlease re-run this script as an Administrator."
Exit
}

$appPool = $branchName
$site = "Default Web Site"

*Import-Module WebAdministration*

#Add APPPool
New-WebAppPool -Name $appPool -Force 

 #Create Applications
New-WebApplication -Name $branchName -Site $site -PhysicalPath $sourceFolder -   ApplicationPool $appPool -Force
```